# Uncaught TypeError: L.geoJSON is not a function

Tags: leaflet, geojson

[image]

I am new to Leaflet and trying to add popup in leaflet map. I saw the example in leaflet website to add geojson polygon and popup on it.
However when i tried to run it shows error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: L.geoJSON is not a function"

and not showing my polygon on map also, can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
 integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
 crossorigin=""/>
 

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
 integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo="
 crossorigin=""></script>
 <!-- <script src="Data/UPState.js"></script> -->

 <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-ajax/2.1.0/leaflet.ajax.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/village.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
        body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    html,
    body,
    #map {
        height: 97%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {

var popupContent = "<p>village Name: <b>" +
        feature.properties.NAME + "</br> population" +
        feature.properties.TOT_P ;
                
if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
}
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
};

    var mapOptions = {
        center: [30.317520, 78.038341],
        zoom: 10
     }

    var map = L.map('map',mapOptions );
    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://server.arcgisonline.com">ESRI Map</a>'
    }).addTo(map);


    var village = L.geoJSON(villageData, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup('<h5 class="customheader">' + feature.properties.NAME + '</h5><table ><thead><tr><th>PROPERTIES</th><th>NAME</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Name</td><td> ' + feature.properties.NAME + '</td></tr><tr><td>District</td><td>' + feature.properties.DISTRICT_1 + '</td></tr><tr><td>Tehsil</td><td>' + feature.properties.Tehsil + '</td></tr></tbody></table >');
        }
    });
    map.addLayer(village);




</script>
```

below is gejson saved in javascript file (its a big file hence pasting part of it here)

```
var villageData = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "village",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SID": "05", "DID": "05", "TID": "0001", "VILL_CODE": "00452200", "C_CODE01": "0505000100452200", "NAME": "PIVNAL", "UID": 43866, "CENSUS_COD": 505000000000000.0, "STATE": 5, "DISTRICT": 5, "SUB_DIST": 1, "TOWN_VILL": 452200, "WARD": 0, "EB": 0, "LEVEL": "VILLAGE", "NAME_1": "Pivnal", "TRU": "Rural", "No_HH": "38", "TOT_P": "299", "TOT_M": 159, "TOT_F": 140, "P_06": 62, "M_06": 38, "F_06": 24, "P_SC": 13, "M_SC": 7, "F_SC": 6, "P_ST": 286, "M_ST": 152, "F_ST": 134, "P_LIT": 102, "M_LIT": 65, "F_LIT": 37, "P_ILL": 197, "M_ILL": 94, "F_ILL": 103, "TOT_WORK_P": 122, "TOT_WORK_M": 70, "TOT_WORK_F": 52, "MAINWORK_P": 13, "MAINWORK_M": 11, "MAINWORK_F": 2, "MAIN_CL_P": 8, "MAIN_CL_M": 6, "MAIN_CL_F": 2, "MAIN_AL_P": 0, "MAIN_AL_M": 0, "MAIN_AL_F": 0, "MAIN_HH_P": 0, "MAIN_HH_M": 0, "MAIN_HH_F": 0, "MAIN_OT_P": 5, "MAIN_OT_M": 5, "MAIN_OT_F": 0, "MARGWORK_P": 109, "MARGWORK_M": 59, "MARGWORK_F": 50, "MARG_CL_P": 100, "MARG_CL_M": 50, "MARG_CL_F": 50, "MARG_AL_P": 2, "MARG_AL_M": 2, "MARG_AL_F": 0, "MARG_HH_P": 0, "MARG_HH_M": 0, "MARG_HH_F": 0, "MARG_OT_P": 7, "MARG_OT_M": 7, "MARG_OT_F": 0, "NON_WORK_P": 177, "NON_WORK_M": 89, "NON_WORK_F": 88, "ST_CODE": 5, "DIST_CODE": 5, "THSIL_CODE": 1, "BLOCK_CODE": 28, "V_CT_CODE": 452200, "VILL_NAME": "Pivnal", "AREA": "248", "T_HH": "38", "T_P": 299.0, "T_M": "159", "T_F": 140, "SC_P": 13, "SC_M": 7, "SC_F": 6, "ST_P": 286, "ST_M": 152, "ST_F": 134, "EDU_FAC": 1, "P_SCH": 2, "RANG_P_SCH": 0, "M_SCH": 0, "RANG_M_SCH": 1, "S_SCH": 0, "S_S_SCH": 0, "COLLEGE": 0, "RANG_COLL": 3, "IND_SCH": 0, "TR_SCH": 0, "ADLT_LT_CT": 0, "OTH_SCH": 0, "MEDI_FAC": 2, "ALL_HOSP": 0, "RANG_ALL": 3, "AYU_HOSP": 0, "UN_HOSP": 0, "HOM_HOSP": 0, "ALL_DISP": 0, "AYU_DISP": 0, "UN_DISP": 0, "HOM_DISP": 0, "MCW_CNTR": 0, "RANG_MCW": 3, "M_HOME": 0, "CWC": 0, "H_CNTR": 0, "PH_CNTR": 0, "RANG_PHC": 3, "PHS_CNT": 0, "FWC_CNTR": 0, "TB_CLN": 0, "N_HOME": 0, "RMP": 0, "SMP": 0, "CHW": 0, "OTH_CNTR": 0, "DRNK_WAT_F": 1, "RANG_WAT_F": 0, "TAP": 1, "WELL": 2, "TANK": 2, "TUBEWELL": 2, "HANDPUMP": 2, "RIVER": 2, "CANAL": 2, "LAKE": 1, "SPRING": 2, "OTHER": 2, "SOU_SUMM": "T", "RANG_SS": 0, "SS_CODE": null, "P_T_FAC": 2, "POST_OFF": "0", "RANG_PO": 3, "TELE_OFF": 0, "POST_TELE": 0, "PHONE": 0, "RANG_PHONE": 3, "COMM_FAC": 2, "BS_FAC": 2, "RANG_BS": 3, "RS_FAC": 2, "RANG_RS": 3, "NW_FAC": 2, "RANG_NW": 3, "BANK_FAC": 2, "COMM_BANK": 0, "RANG_COMM": 3, "COOP_BANK": 0, "RANG_COOP": 3, "CRSOC_FAC": 2, "AC_SOC": 0, "RANG_ACS": 3, "NAC_SOC": 0, "RANG_NAC": 3, "OTHER_SOC": 0, "RANG_OTH": 3, "RC_FAC": 2, "C_V_HALL": 0, "RANG_CV": 3, "SP_CL_FAC": 0, "RANG_SPCL": 3, "ST_AU_FAC": 0, "RANG_STAU": 3, "APP_PR": 2, "APP_MR": 2, "APP_FP": 1, "APP_NAVRIV": 2, "APP_NAVCAN": 2, "APP_NW": 2, "NEAR_TOWN": "Chakrata", "DIST_TOWN": 171, "POWER_SUPL": "1", "POWER_DOM": 1, "POWER_AGR": "2", "POWER_OTH": 2, "POWER_ALL": 2, "PAP_MAG": 2, "NEWS_PAP": null, "MAGAZINE": null, "A_INCEXP": "1", "TOT_INC": "33000", "TOT_EXP": 32000.0, "MAN_COMM1": "Blankets", "MAN_COMM2": null, "MAN_COMM3": null, "LAND_FORES": "10", "CANAL_GOVT": 0.0, "CANAL_PVT": 0.0, "WELL_WO_EL": 0.0, "WELL_W_EL": 0.0, "TW_WO_EL": 0.0, "TW_W_EL": 0.0, "TANK_IRR": 0.0, "RIVER_IRR": 0.0, "LAKE_IRR": 0.0, "W_FALL": 0.0, "OTH_IRR": 0.0, "TOT_IRR": 0.0, "UN_IRR": 76.6, "CULT_WASTE": 169.8, "AREA_NA_CU": 1.4 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 77.782482395738015, 30.932132248101045 ], [ 77.782508071137869, 30.931975684484648 ], [ 77.781988912408551, 30.932200945223958 ], [ 77.779723316133101, 30.933674985101437 ], [ 77.779028757132821, 30.934220504789508 ], [ 77.778419468468414, 30.93482424796343 ], [ 77.777620692059585, 30.93554939026437 ], [ 77.776321199474452, 30.936523113039492 ], [ 77.775221839823402, 30.937492074655918 ], [ 77.774025179208095, 30.938347860633936 ], [ 77.77327123422981, 30.938945921037433 ], [ 77.771163390385823, 30.94008608578994 ], [ 77.769909692863479, 30.940783997923674 ], [ 77.768042889347143, 30.941523767917086 ], [ 77.764646460160449, 30.942605740308704 ], [ 77.763702777193203, 30.942873943314506 ], [ 77.762830194902392, 30.943343927969043 ], [ 77.762090356739904, 30.944094848048369 ], [ 77.761482124084608, 30.944599551471729 ], [ 77.760869717162933, 30.945129204917201 ], [ 77.759263896547353, 30.94596399775833 ], [ 77.75706677473795, 30.946609720872772 ], [ 77.755467835782994, 30.947329750904196 ], [ 77.753479576700684, 30.947829803712839 ], [ 77.752010490115396, 30.948283167255383 ], [ 77.751131360405239, 30.948440320334232 ], [ 77.751098921284978, 30.948446119871388 ], [ 77.751120731712717, 30.949137815198103 ], [ 77.748624829297256, 30.948655682562279 ], [ 77.749407004655581, 30.954676553488852 ], [ 77.751184380019495, 30.958677669616737 ], [ 77.755253876316203, 30.961736896936785 ], [ 77.768805108644784, 30.971921742899589 ], [ 77.778766024272599, 30.972071128523165 ], [ 77.785818817482294, 30.970728707068975 ], [ 77.793260275129015, 30.967382415787309 ], [ 77.798954998249627, 30.963308025864318 ], [ 77.798600843138672, 30.962831421360622 ], [ 77.798290114058403, 30.962392300549926 ], [ 77.794982483478989, 30.95674547995123 ], [ 77.793551334196565, 30.954168966446261 ], [ 77.791441349433839, 30.950342399881151 ], [ 77.788955267051904, 30.945185982689232 ], [ 77.787253919973807, 30.941936957880298 ], [ 77.786124972001403, 30.940401822208585 ], [ 77.786004931797123, 30.939866114167902 ], [ 77.783418710331588, 30.934584637562853 ], [ 77.782653442141395, 30.933055617577935 ], [ 77.782506124633102, 30.932484744052687 ], [ 77.782484603021928, 30.932400064653891 ], [ 77.782505332233995, 30.932285461537216 ], [ 77.782482395738015, 30.932132248101045 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SID": "05", "DID": "05", "TID": "0001", "VILL_CODE": "00450400", "C_CODE01": "0505000100450400", "NAME": "BHATGARHI", "UID": 43867, "CENSUS_COD": 505000000000000.0, "STATE": 5, "DISTRICT": 5, "SUB_DIST": 1, "TOWN_VILL": 450400, "WARD": 0, "EB": 0, "LEVEL": "VILLAGE", "NAME_1": "Bhatgarhi", "TRU": "Rural", "No_HH": "75", "TOT_P": "500", "TOT_M": 258, "TOT_F": 242, "P_06": 80, "M_06": 44, "F_06": 36, "P_SC": 161, "M_SC": 81, "F_SC": 80, "P_ST": 313, "M_ST": 160, "F_ST": 153, "P_LIT": 252, "M_LIT": 153, "F_LIT": 99, "P_ILL": 248, "M_ILL": 105, "F_ILL": 143, "TOT_WORK_P": 119, "TOT_WORK_M": 100, "TOT_WORK_F": 19, "MAINWORK_P": 74, "MAINWORK_M": 65, "MAINWORK_F": 9, "MAIN_CL_P": 58, "MAIN_CL_M": 49, "MAIN_CL_F": 9, "MAIN_AL_P": 0, "MAIN_AL_M": 0, "MAIN_AL_F": 0, "MAIN_HH_P": 1, "MAIN_HH_M": 1, "MAIN_HH_F": 0, "MAIN_OT_P": 15, "MAIN_OT_M": 15, "MAIN_OT_F": 0, "MARGWORK_P": 45, "MARGWORK_M": 35, "MARGWORK_F": 10, "MARG_CL_P": 8, "MARG_CL_M": 3, "MARG_CL_F": 5, "MARG_AL_P": 18, "MARG_AL_M": 13, "MARG_AL_F": 5, "MARG_HH_P": 3, "MARG_HH_M": 3, "MARG_HH_F": 0, "MARG_OT_P": 16, "MARG_OT_M": 16, "MARG_OT_F": 0, "NON_WORK_P": 381, "NON_WORK_M": 158, "NON_WORK_F": 223, "ST_CODE": 5, "DIST_CODE": 5, "THSIL_CODE": 1, "BLOCK_CODE": 28, "V_CT_CODE": 450400, "VILL_NAME": "Bhatgarhi", "AREA": "496", "T_HH": "75", "T_P": 500.0, "T_M": "258", "T_F": 242, "SC_P": 161, "SC_M": 81, "SC_F": 80, "ST_P": 313, "ST_M": 
{..................................................................
```

Comment: You have one script reference too much (reference to some old version of Leaflet): `<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>`. Leave it out and it'll be OK.